# vsce publish fails - VS Code Extension using pnpm/yarn

Tags: vscode-extensions, yarnpkg, pnpm, yarn-v2

**Versions:**

- vsce version 1.71.0
- node version v10.15.3
- npm version 6.4.1

vsce publish fails with the below message:

> Executing prepublish script 'npm run vscode:prepublish'...
>
> sfdx-command-builder@0.1.0 vscode:prepublish C:\Projects\VS Code Extensions\sfdx-command-builder
> npm run compile
>
> sfdx-command-builder@0.1.0 compile C:\Projects\VS Code Extensions\sfdx-command-builder
> tsc -p ./
>
> ERROR Command failed: npm list --production --parseable --depth=99999
> npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.14.0
> npm ERR! missing: minimist@0.0.8, required by mkdirp@0.5.1
> npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by ignore-walk@3.0.3
> npm ERR! missing: brace-expansion@1.1.11, required by minimatch@3.0.4
> npm ERR! missing: balanced-match@1.0.0, required by brace-expansion@1.1.11
> npm ERR! missing: concat-map@0.0.1, required by brace-expansion@1.1.11
> npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by npmlog@4.1.2
> npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.4, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
> npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.2, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
> npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.2, required by string_decoder@1.1.1
> npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by gauge@2.7.4
> npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by gauge@2.7.4
> npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by gauge@2.7.4
> npm ERR! missing: code-point-at@1.1.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
> npm ERR! missing: is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
> npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by string-width@1.0.2
> npm ERR! missing: number-is-nan@1.0.1, required by is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
> npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@2.1.1, required by strip-ansi@3.0.1
> npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by wide-align@1.1.3
> npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.4, required by glob@7.1.6
> npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by glob@7.1.6
> npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by glob@7.1.6
> npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by inflight@1.0.6
> npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by inflight@1.0.6
> npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by once@1.4.0
> npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.9.0, required by tar@4.4.13
> npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by tar@4.4.13
> npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.2, required by tar@4.4.13
> npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.1.1, required by tar@4.4.13
> npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.9.0, required by fs-minipass@1.2.7
> npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.2, required by minipass@2.9.0
> npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.1.1, required by minipass@2.9.0
> npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.9.0, required by minizlib@1.3.3

Comment: Edit the question to reveal your package.json.

Answer (score 6):

This happens because the extension's linker fails to resolve the dependencies.

To fix it do the following depending on which node package manager your repo uses:

- `yarn` repo:

  ```bash
  vsce publish --yarn -p $my_token
  ```
- `pnpm` repo:

  1. if you have no runtime dependencies you can keep it simple, just add this to your `package.json`

     ```json
     "scripts": {
         "package": "pnpm vsce package --no-dependencies",
         "publish": "pnpm vsce publish --no-dependencies"
     }
     ```

     or run the command `vsce publish patch --no-dependencies` (use `minor` or `major` instead of `patch` as needed,  see [semver](https://semver.org/))
  2. if you have runtime dependencies you need to bundle them first, so additionally to (1) also add this to your `package.json`

     ```json
     "scripts": {
         "vscode:prepublish": "npm run esbuild-base -- --minify",
         "esbuild-base": "esbuild ./src/extension.ts --bundle --outfile=out/main.js --external:vscode --format=cjs --platform=node"
     }
     ```

For either case you'll obviously need to install vsce with

```bash
pnpm i -D vsce # or `yarn add -D vsce`
```

and in the 2nd pnpm case you'll also need esbuild too

```bash
pnpm i -D esbuild
```

See more info in the [related Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-vsce/issues/421#issuecomment-1038911725).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run `npm install` before running `vsce publish`?

I experienced the issue when using yarn. The solution for me was to add `--yarn` to the command:

```sh
vsce publish --yarn -p $my_token
```

Source: @joaomoreno's comment in https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-vsce/issues/246#issuecomment-396528264

Comment: What if I'm using pnpm? I tried `--pnpm` and it gives me error: unknown option '--pnpm'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript which is seemingly a less popular choice and facing this error then try this

```
npm i --save-dev webpack webpack-cli
```

It solved my error and let me publish by adding desired dependencies.